# htaccess redirection with query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string, redirect

My htaccess rule is :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param1=val1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /page1 [L,R=301]
```

This redirects to the url : `http://myhost/page1?param1=val1`

If my url is : `http://myhost/index.php?param1=val1&param2=val2`

should redirects to : `http://myhost/page1?param2=val2`

That means, it should not include the matched query string in **RewriteCond**

Answer (score 1):

Just use a group matching:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param1=val1(?:&(.+))?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /page1?%1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Or `^param1=val1(?:&(.+))?$` without the `&`.

Comment: Its working if it has the params. For e.g.,

If my url is : `http://myhost/index.php?param1=val1&param2=val2`

should redirects to : `http://myhost/page1?param2=val2`. This is working fine. But if I has the url : `http://myhost/index.php?param1=val1`

then it is getting redirected to `http://myhost/page1?%1`

I want to get rid of that `?%1` part if it does not has the parameters

Comment: @Govind Try using a `B` flag with the `R=301` one. If that doesn't help, you'd have to break the rules into two separate ones.

Comment: @hjpotter92 : It is not working with `B` flag. So I have achieved that with 2 rules.. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*&?(param\d=val\d)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /page1?%1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

With:
`http://myhost/index.php?param1=val1` -> `http://myhost/page1?param1=val1`
and
`http://myhost/index.php?param1=val1&param2=val2` -> `http://myhost/page1?param2=val2`
But only if the real name is param1, param2, param3...